# Override numpy array string representation

Tags: python, numpy

`with np.printoptions`'s [`formatter`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.set_printoptions.html) argument allows controlling formatting of individual array elements. Is there something for the entire array?

I'm looking for something to the effect of

```py
arr_trunc = lambda x: np.array2string(x).splitlines()[0]
with np.printoptions(formatter={'array': arr_trunc}):
    print(np.random.randn(50, 50))
```

This way, `dc = {n: np.random.randn(50, 50) for n in 'abcd'}` can be printed via `print(dc)` rather than having to code traversing iterables or nested structures. Also, above code fails with infinite recursion.

I can't set `np.ndarray.__str__`. Do I need to get more hackish and override `array2string` itself? The methods are wrapped, so it may not be safe to do so directly.

---

If it helps, here's a [`deepmap`](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/242369/210581) implem, so one could make a "`deepprint`" that still has to be applied like `deepprint(dc)`, which is better than nothing. So one might intercept Python's string-fier with `if isinstance(x, np.ndarray)` while leaving everything else unchanged.

Comment: `dc` is a `dict`, with string keys and array values.  I suspect `print(dc)` calls the `repr` display of those arrays.

Comment: Yes, the goal's to override `__repr__` and/or `__str__` (if that's the only way).